# ¿Cómo puedo decirle a git que ignore ciertos ficheros? No es gitignore

Tags: git, git-commit

Quizas no he formulado correctamente la pregunta del título, la situación es la siguiente:

Imagina que:

- Estás trabajando en tu propia rama local.
- Estás trabajando en una funcionalidad grande y por ende, tienes unos 20 - 30 ficheros modificados.
- Necesitas cambiarte a master local, hacer un pull de los últimos cambios y cambiarte a tu rama para hacer un merge con master (vamos, para tener los últimos cambios).
- Imagina que git no te deja cambiarte a master porque hay muchos ficheros modificados en tu rama local.

**¿Cuál es la mejor forma de actuar frente a esa situación?**

Yo siempre he hecho dos:

1. Si la funcionalidad está terminada o casi terminada (99%), hago un commit, luego hago el merge, luego aplico las últimas modificaciones y hago push de todo.
2. Si la funcionalidad no está terminada, voy al directorio del proyecto, me copio los ficheros, me cambio a master de manera forzada (pierdo los cambios), hago el merge, y vuelvo a copiar los ficheros al proyecto. Sin embargo, esto es viable cuando la funcionalidad no es grande (pocos ficheros modificados).

En este caso, **no puedo usar ni la 1 ni la 2**.

Me gustaría saber la forma correcta de actuar frente a esta situación, **¿hay un comando para decirle a GIT que no me elimine esos ficheros cuando me cambie a la rama master?**

Comment: ¿No te resultaría útil hacer un [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) antes de cambiarte a la rama master? Puede ayudarte a hacer algo parecido a la opción 2.

Comment: Aunque no creas, nunca la habia usado. Muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es el comando `git stash`

Este comando hace una especie de commit, pero sin llegar a ser commit, es como si fuera un commit temporal, permitiéndote cambiar de ramas sin tener el problema de los archivos modificados.

Para guardar los archivos:

```sh
git stash save "mensaje descriptivo"
```

Si tienes archivos nuevos (untracked) tienes que añadir la opción `-u` o `--include-untracked`:

```sh
git stash save "mensaje descriptivo" -u
```

Para ver los stash que tienes:

```sh
git stash list
```

Para recuperar los cambios del último stash:

Este comando te recupera los cambios y luego lo elimina (el stash, no los cambios)

```sh
git stash pop
```

Para recuperar los cambios de un stash concreto:

`n` → número de estash que te dice el comando `list`

```sh
git stash apply stash@{n}
```

Para eliminar un stash concreto:

`n` → número de estash que te dice el comando `list`

```sh
git stash drop stash@{n}
```

Infórmate más a fondo por internet, pero en esencia con eso te debería ser suficiente.

Te dejo por aquí el link oficial: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

---

**Update:**

Cuando escribí la respuesta no lo sabía, pero poco después descubrí que al comando `git stash pop` puedes añadir el stash concreto con `stash@{n}` (siendo `n`, como siempre, el número de stash dado por el comando `git stash list`).

Es decir, si añades el stash especifico te hace el pop de este, sino te hará del último stash realizado es decir el `stash@{0}`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy completa y bien explicada.

Comment: Si hago un git stash apply stash@{n} y quiero eliminar esos cambios pero no eliminar el codigo, es decir, no eliminar el stash, o dicho de otra forma, quiero revertir git stash apply stash@{n} sin perder los cambios (para usarlos en el futuro), debo crear otro stash o como debo hacer?

Comment: @Carlos si haces un `git stash apply stash@{n}` se te aplican los cambios del stash pero sin eliminarlo, por ello podrás hacer nuevamente el apply en un futuro y te añadirá los mismos cambios.

Answer (score 2):

La situación que describes se maneja normalmente con *la caleta* (o sea, el `stash`).

Si cuando haces una operación como merge/checkout git no te lo permite porque tienes archivos modificados, lo que haces es *encaletar* los archivos modificados:

```
git stash save "ya regreso"
```

Con eso git guarda los cambios que tienes hechos en los archivos de tu árbol de trabajo y los deja limpios, como si no los hubieras tocado. Entonces haces lo que necesites hacer (merge o checkout o X), cuando terminas de hacer lo que necesitabas (digamos que era un merge.... te quedas donde estás, si hiciste un checkout de *otra rama*, pues regresas a la rama original) y entonces haces:

```
git stash pop
```

Y con eso git va a aplicar los cambios que habías guardado antes sobre los archivos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.